# How to add fonts to iText?

Tags: java, itext

How to add fonts to iText Java API?In which file of source code I have to make changes to add my set of fonts which is located on my system in .ttf format?

Comment: What you done so far? And Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6922959/1064610) helpfull?

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=195):

```
BaseFont base = BaseFont.createFont("c:/windows/fonts/arial.ttf", BaseFont.WINANSI);
Font font = new Font(base, 11f, Font.BOLD);
```

See the [BaseFont](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/BaseFont.html) class too

Comment: in which file i have to make the above changes?

Comment: There where you need it, I guess in your odf creation methode.

Comment: thank u..but please be specific...In which file of the source i have to change???

Comment: What are you using itext for? to create pdf files?

Comment: so why do you need a different font? anyway you can write the code in your extraction methode.