# Text area's Font family is not changing

Tags: java, textarea

In a java program, I created a `TextArea` a `MenuBar`, 
But I am unable to change font family of the `TextArea`

Only

`ta.setFont(new Font(Font.SERIF,Font.PLAIN,14));`

is working since here I used `Font` class constants.

But this is not working...

`ta.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,14));`

After this statement the font in `TextArea` is still default. Neither "Comic Sans MS" is working..

Comment: Are you using `SWING` or `AWT` or `JAVAFX` components ? Because in the documentation of Oracle I could't find a method for any of the frameworks where you can use something like this `setFont("Arial",Font.PLAIN,14);`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
textArea.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 14));
```

Comment: Text is still default

Comment: Have you copied exactly the code above or have you adapted to your code? For you code, the solution is: `ta.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 14));`

Comment: I have found out from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922959/how-to-add-new-fonts-to-itext-using-java `BaseFont base = BaseFont.createFont("c:/windows/fonts/arial.ttf",BaseFont.WINANSI);
Font font = new Font(base, 11f, Font.BOLD);`

Comment: But I can't find BaseFont in java doc

Comment: Forget about BaseFont. I suggest you take look at this site http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#createFont(int,%20java.io.File).